# NSNotification arrived with broken object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotifications

i'm posting notification in this manner:

```
...
IVSession *newSession = [[[IVSession alloc] initWithDictionary:propertyDict] autorelease];     

NSDictionary *notifParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:newSession  forKey:@"session"];        
NSNotification *newSessionNotif = [NSNotification notificationWithName:IVNewSessionNotificaiton object:self userInfo:notifParams]; 
...
```

IVSession interface:

```
@interface IVSession : IVMappableObject {
    NSString *_ssid;
    NSNumber *_uid;    
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *sessionID;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSNumber *userID;
```

and init method:

```
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        NSDictionary *mapping = [self elementToPropertyMappings];
        for (NSString *key in mapping)
            [self setValue:[dict objectForKey:key] forKey:[mapping objectForKey:key]];
    }    
    return self;
}
```

but at the method, called for this notification, i'm receiving broken `newSession` object - its properties `ssid` and `uid` are invalid summaries:

```
-(void)didOpenSession:(NSNotification *)newSession
{
    if (receivedSession)
        [receivedSession release];
    receivedSession =  [[newSession userInfo] objectForKey:@"session"];
}
```

where is my fault?

Comment: IVNewSessionNotificaiton is spelled wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code looks ok to me... have you verified that the IVSession object contains what you expect it to, after assembling things, but prior to posting the notification?

Comment: well, actually i've done with this problem - there was no problem at all. just debugger sometimes shows "invalid summary" for valid objects